# Upload file from google app engine to google drive using java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth, google-drive-api

I have received pdf file from email successfully but I have to store that Pdf file into google drive.here is my code

```
private static void uploadFile(InputStream is) {

             com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
             fileMetadata.setTitle(fileName);
             fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/pdf");

             HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
             JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
             AppIdentityCredential credential = new AppIdentityCredential.Builder(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).build();
             // API_KEY is from the Google Console as a server API key
             GoogleClientRequestInitializer keyInitializer = new CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer("My API_key here");
             Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)

                 .setApplicationName("My app name here")
                 .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
                 .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(keyInitializer)
                 .build();

             try {
                Drive.Files.Insert in= service.files().insert(fileMetadata, new InputStreamContent("application/pdf",is));
                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File retFile =in.execute();
                if(retFile!=null){
                    System.out.println("Drive retFile:"+retFile.getTitle());    
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Drive Error:"+e.toString());
            }
          }
```

I have checked associated account Google Drive nothing is uploaded.

and i have googled past 1 week i didn't find any clear documentation for uploading file from GAE to google dive.

thanks in advance...

Comment: It's great that you posted your solution. This is very helpful to future users. Do you think you could post your solution as an "answer" on your own question? This is usually how it's done on stackoverflow. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have find the solution,first we need to understand GAE service account and associated Google account has separate drive storage.

My above code store the file to GAE service account drive (Service Account which has no UI) so it's not visible to our associated Google account.

So we need share the service account file to associated Google account.Here is my modified code

```
private static void uploadFile(InputStream is) {

            com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
            fileMetadata.setTitle(curDateWithFormat()+"-"+fileName);
            fileMetadata.setMimeType("application/pdf");


             HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
             JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
             AppIdentityCredential credential = new AppIdentityCredential.Builder(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE)).build();
             // API_KEY is from the Google Console as a server API key
             GoogleClientRequestInitializer keyInitializer = new CommonGoogleClientRequestInitializer("AIzaSyCKLTs_D2zYJepjno8OSVy-2CItYayvu0M");
             Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)

                 .setApplicationName("TimesheetPDFParser")
                 .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
                 .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(keyInitializer)
                 .build();

             try {
                Drive.Files.Insert in= service.files().insert(fileMetadata, new InputStreamContent("application/pdf",is));
                com.google.api.services.drive.model.File retFile =in.execute();

                if(retFile!=null){
                    Permission newPermission = new Permission();
                    newPermission.setValue("here your email id @gmail.com");
                    newPermission.setType("user");
                    newPermission.setRole("reader");//owner and writer role throws 400 BAD_REQUEST exception    
                    service.permissions().insert(retFile.getId(), newPermission).execute();

                    System.out.println("Drive retFile:"+retFile.getId());   
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Drive Error:"+e.toString());
            }
          }
```

Now you can see your file in shared account drive in shared with me option.

Referred from:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert